# Atom autocomplete html "href" Win10 for html not working

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

I am new to Atom and used brackets so far. How can I achieve, that in plain html atom helps me to autocomplete urls. I have installed v1.27.2.

```
<a href="ind ... do smth ... ">
```

should be completed to

```
<a href="index.html">
```

Tried strg + Enter  result:  nothing happend

Tried enter result: nothing except the expected line break happend

Tried to modify config.cson file for atom- as described on git.hub on a similar issue

```
"autocomplete-paths":
 scopes: [
  {
  scopes: [
    "text.html.basic"
  ]
  prefixes: [
    "src=['\"]"
    "href=['\"]"
  ]
  extensions: [
    "js"
    "png"
    "gif"
    "jpeg"
    "jpg"
    "tiff"
    "html"
  ]
  relative: true
}
```

]

No success at all. Thank you very much in advance and kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally it was really simple. (Only for the case that someone else will have same problems... ). Following worked for me.

settings / packages / autocomplete-paths / plugin settings.

activate -> enable for HTML support (It's disabled by default... .)

Max File Count -> 8000 (Default is 2000)